# PHP - Return value if 2 out of 3 true

Tags: php

I have 3 image fields, and in the front end template need to know if any 1, 2 or all 3 are set so I can style them differently based on the answer.

So eg, `if($img1 && $img2 && $img3)`  for any 1 image. I'm looking for a function in PHP to return the number of images set (ie 1,2,3).

Just a count based on whether the image is set, or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: if your styling is based purely on the number of images, then yes, a simple count would suffice.

Comment: OK Marc B, I wasn't meaning a built in PHP function to do it all for me...I meant some ideas on an efficient way to return what I want....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!!` to convert a value to a boolean. Then you can add these together: `true` acts as `1`, `false` as `0`. So:

```
$count = !!$img1 + !!$img2 + !!$img3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to figure out how many have values, the following will work.

```
$count = 0;

$count += $img1 ? 1 : 0;
$count += $img2 ? 1 : 0;
$count += $img3 ? 1 : 0;

echo $count;
```

This will output a number between 0 and 3.

Comment: Why not add 1,2 and 4, so you can tell which one these are

Comment: @Rizier123 Because the OP wants to do something just based on how many are set, it doesn't matter which ones.

Comment: @Rizier123 I agree a bitwise operation would be great, not only does it let you know how many are picked, but also which ones were picked.